# Minimal bivariate diophantine equation solution space

Tags: polynomials, diophantine-equations

I am facing the following type of diophantine equations:

$$
axy + bx + cy + d = 0
$$

Where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are integers and solutions for $x$, $y$ in the integers are seeked. If $a=0$ one can apply the extended euclidean algorithm. $x$ and $y$ can then be viewed as generated by a new parameter $t$ and linear forms:

$$
    x = et + f \\
    y = gt + h
$$

Can something similar be said when $a\ne0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$axy+bx+cy+d=0$; $a^2xy+abx+acy+ad=0$; $(ax+c)(ay+b)+ad-bc=0$; $(ax+c)(ay+b)=bc-ad$. So what you have to do is factor $bc-ad$; then for every factorization $bc-ad=rs$, you have to see whether the simultaneous equations $ax+c=r$, $ay+b=s$ have a solution.